# How to upload multiple images in WordPress through the restful API?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

```
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('file', mainProductImage[0])
formData.append('title', product.product_name)
fetch(POST_IMAGE_API_URL, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: authHeader(),
  body: formData,
})
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    dispatch(
      postProduct({
        name: product.product_name,
        description: product.product_description,
        images: [{ src: data.source_url }],
      }),
    )
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
        setIsUploading(false)
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
}
```

Above is my code right now.
This JavaScript code only works to upload a single image to WordPress.
How to solve this problem to upload multiple images at once time?